# Laravel 5.7: I inject bunch on classes into constructor but League\Csv\Reader is the only one that doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I have some artisan commands to perform some CLI logic.

```
class SyncFooCommand extends AbstractBaseSyncCommand
class SyncBarCommand extends AbstractBaseSyncCommand
class SyncBazCommand extends AbstractBaseSyncCommand
```

Each artisan command extends `abstract class AbstractBaseSyncCommand extends Command implements SyncInterface`.

Thanks to that inside the abstract parent class I can put some shared logic.

I inject Carbon or FileSystem and both work in child classes like a charm.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands\Sync;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Factory as Filesystem;
use League\Csv\Reader;

abstract class AbstractBaseSyncCommand extends Command implements SyncInterface
{
    protected $carbon;
    protected $fileSystem;
    protected $reader;

    public function __construct(
        Carbon $carbon,
        FileSystem $fileSystem,
        Reader $reader
    ) {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->carbon = $carbon; // works like a charm
        $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem; // works like a charm
        $this->reader = $reader; // fails, why?
    }
}
```

In `SyncWhateverCommand` I can easily call & use `$this->carbon` or `$this->fileSystem` but as soon as it hits the `$this->reader` I get:

```
   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  : Target [League\Csv\Reader] is not instantiable while building [App\Console\Commands\Sync\SyncFooCommand].

  at /home/vagrant/code/foo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:945
    941|         } else {
    942|             $message = "Target [$concrete] is not instantiable.";
    943|         }
    944|
  > 945|         throw new BindingResolutionException($message);
    946|     }
    947|
    948|     /**
    949|      * Throw an exception for an unresolvable primitive.
```

What's wrong? [The installation](http://csv.thephpleague.com/9.0/installation/) was easy and didn't require to do any bindings. What am I missing?

To sum up:

```
$csv = $this->reader->createFromPath($path, 'r'); // fails, but I want to use it this way

$csv = Reader::createFromPath($path, 'r'); // works but I don't want facades because they look ugly
```

Comment: what class have you binded in `appserviceprovider class`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your app should know how to retrieve it? Like

```
$this->app->bind('SomeAbstraction', function ($app) {
    return new Implementation();
});
```